# Regex statement to match parts of an URL

Tags: regex

Let's say I have this string;  `https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/000000000000000000/000000000000000000/imagename.png`

I currently have `[^.]+$`, but this only matches **png** and I would like to match `image` too.
How would I go about doing this? Could it be possible to have one Regex statement, that matches `image` *and* `png`?

Comment: Use `[^/]+$`...

Comment: That would literally match `imagename.png`, I'd like to only match `imagename`

Comment: Then use `[^/]+(?=\.[^/.]*$)`

Comment: @RagingLink You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match `image` and `png` you could make use of 2 [capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and an anchor `$` to assert the end of the string.

```
([^/]+)\.([^/.]+)$
```

See the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/B1o0jJ/1)

**Explanation**

- `([^/]+)` Capturing group to capture the filename. Match 1+ times not a forward slash
- .` Match a literal dot
- `([^./]+)` Capturing group to capture the extension. Match 1+ times not a dot or a forward slash
- `$` Assert the end of the string

Answer (score 1):

Try this regular expression to math full name  ([example](https://regex101.com/r/bgYfk0/1))

```
[^\/]+$
```

or this to match name without extension ([example](https://regex101.com/r/bgYfk0/4))

```
[^\/]+(?=\.png$)
```

explanation

- `[^\/]+` match any character except slash (in JS we can reduce this to `[^/]`)
- `(?=\.png$)` a positive lookahead which requires ".png" extension (and end of string $) after matched letters.

```js
let s="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/000000000000000000/000000000000000000/imagename.png";

console.log( s.match(/[^/]+$/)[0] )
console.log( s.match(/[^/]+(?=\.png$)/)[0] )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only match `imagename` in your string use

```
[^/]+(?=\.[^/.]*$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dPQX7P/1)

If the extension can be *optional* use

```
[^/]+(?=(?:\.[^/.]*)?$)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dPQX7P/2)

Note that depending on how you declare the regex you might need to escape `/` chars inside the patterns.

**Details**

- `[^/]+` - one or more chars other than `/` (`[^/]` is a (*negated character class*)
- `(?=(?:\.[^/.]*)?$)` - a positive lookahead that requires the following patterns to match immediately to the right of the current location:

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `[^/.]*` - zero or more chars other than `/` and `.`
  - `$` - end of string.

The `(?:\.[^/.]*)?` is an optional non-capturing group, the whole sequence of patterns inside is optional.